# Importing only one class of a css file

Tags: css

I have a web page, Page-A, that uses a primary css file. I have other pages, Page-B, that use another primary css file. I'd like to use two classes of the Page-B css file into Page-A, but I do not want to override other classes and functions of Page-A css with this Page-B css file.

Is it possible to import only two classes of a css file instead of all its classes. In other words, is it possible to constrain an @import or link to load only a few classes?

Comment: You would need to refactor out the classes into a separate file.

Comment: Why dont you have a common(master) CSS file between these pages, which has the classes that all of them need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to import specific classes from a CSS file.

The correct way to do this would be to create a master CSS file, which all your webpages can share.

1. Delete the classes you need from PageBs css(OPTIONAL), add them to a new CSS file.
2. Link the new file to both the pages.

This way you will not override any classes and have a CSS file which has all the shared classes both pages need.

Comment: Ouch! That would mean reediting all other Pages-B (more than 50 in my case) to add this new master css. I guess I'll just add the classes I need within Page-A within style tags. Thanks for letting me know that it is impossible to import only a few classes.

Answer (score 2):

**No. It's not possible.**

**But:** You can still **prefix** your CSS rules with a class or an ID. It can helps you work with specificity (http://bit.ly/1aODhdu) and with rule importance.

You can also prefix CSS rule which will be **applied-only** for some nodes like `html.one div` `html.two div` so after load second CSS file will be still ignored.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is mark the classes that will be overriding everything with the `!important` tag in CSS, which means that it will not be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

I would just input the two classes you want into the Page-A css file, as there is unfortunately  no way to just import certain classes.

I would suggest making one master CSS file and input into both pages, that way all of your changes are reflected on both pages.